# Flex ArrayCollection: RemoveAll() vs new ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex

When would you want to use removeAll() vs just new ArrayCollection when you want to clear an array collection.

Remove all iterates though each item in the list.  I can't see a case when I would want to use it.

Comment: I can honestly say I've never had a need for removeAll.  I assume there could be memory issues if you just go around creating new ArrayCollection's all the time w/o bothering to clear out the old ones somehow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd probably want to use removeAll in the case where the ArrayCollection contains items with a propertyChange event dispatcher attached to them (with bindings?). The removeAll will clean these events nicely for you.

However, if you use new ArrayCollection the old ArrayCollection will be deallocated from the reference, but may never be garbage collected, because it still has references attached. This could potentially lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

Note that removeAll() will not in fact remove ALL elements from collection in case a filterFunction is defined and applied (.refresh()) and there are any elements in source Array, rejected by this filter.